# C - Problem in finding sum of consecutive numbers

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int start, end, i, sum = 0, temp, x, y, z;
    puts("Please enter the starting number: ");
    scanf("%d", &start);
    temp = start;
    x = start; y = start + 1;
    puts("Please enter the last number till you want to add: ");
    scanf("%d", &end);
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        z = x + y;
        x = z;
        y = y + 1;
    }
    printf("The sum of the numbers starting from %d to %d is %d", temp, end, z);
}
```

Can anyone find what's wrong with this code?

It is working fine for less numbers but when I assign large numbers like 1 to 1000000, it doesn't work i.e. it returns strange values.

**Case 1:**

```
Please enter the starting number:
1

Please enter the last number till you want to add:
100

The sum of the numbers starting from 1 to 100 is 5050
```

But in this case -

**Case 2:**

```
Please enter the starting number:
1


Please enter the last number till you want to add:
1000000


The sum of the numbers starting from 1 to 1000000 is 1784293664
```

**What's wrong in this case?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this value is too long for an `int` and it may overflow, try switching to `unsigned long long `

Comment: Note: Signed Integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: @SouravGhosh undefined behaviour or implementation defined?

Comment: @DavidRanieri I'm pretty sure it's UB, after all, it's a direct example mentioned in the spec.

Comment: Thanks @SouravGhosh, you are right, I was confused with `unsigned` being implementation defined up to version C11

Comment: @DavidRanieri  _Unsigned_ integer overflow was defined behavior in C99 and certainly in C89.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thats odd (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow): The **C11** standard states that for unsigned integers modulo wrapping is the defined behavior and the term overflow never applies: "a computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow."

Comment: @DavidRanieri Re-state: unsigned overflow   is defined in C17, C11, C99, 94, C89.  It is not [implementation defined up to version C11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823077/c-problem-in-finding-sum-of-consecutive-numbers?noredirect=1#comment116381529_65823077).  C89 has:   "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow. because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type"  C89 6.1.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `int` which only have value range `-32,768 to 32,767` or `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647` for `2 byte` and `4 byte` respectively.

You should use `unsigned long long` for your code which have a value range `0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a case of data overflow.

For your example of computing from 1 to 1000000, the sum of consecutive numbers from 1 to x is x(x+1)/2, which is 500.000.500.000, a value largely above the range of an int (2.147.483 647).

Consider using long long int, and don't forget that regardless of the byte size of your variable up to a certain value you'll overflow anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For large numbers you must use `unsigned long long int` instead of `int`. Here `int`  means integer which is up to 3 or 4 digit numbers but when you enter 5 digit numbers or more digit numbers it gives you strange values.

Comment: Hi Dakashayani and welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for contributing an answer. I agree with your answer but please note that unsigned long long character is not a basic C data type, maybe you mean unsigned long long int. Please edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The range of type `int` is not sufficient to represent the value of the sum for large values of `start` and `stop` (for example the sum for `0` to `65536` exceeds `2147483647`). The variables `x`, `y` and `z` should be defined with type `long long` which is guaranteed to represent values up to `9223372036854775807` (9.22E18) or `unsigned long` up to `18446744073709551615` (1.84E19).

Furthermore your algorithm to compute the sum is convoluted, with unnecessary or unused intermediary variables. Simplicity is king!

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int start, end, i;
    long long sum;

    puts("Please enter the starting number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &start) != 1)
        return 1;

    puts("Please enter the last number till you want to add: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &end) != 1)
        return 1;

    sum = 0;
    for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    printf("The sum of the numbers from %d to %d is %lld\n", start, end, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

For positive `start` and `stop` values, there is a direct formula to compute the result. You could replace the `for` loop with this expression:

```
    if (start <= stop) {
        // take the sum of integers from 0 to stop: stop * (stop + 1) / 2
        sum = (long long)stop * (stop + 1) / 2;
        // subtract the sum of integers from 0 to start - 1: (start - 1) * start / 2
        sum -= (long long)start * (start - 1) / 2;
    } else {
        sum = 0;
    }
```

which simplifies as:

```
    if (start <= stop) {
        sum = ((long long)stop + start)(stop - start + 1) / 2;
    } else {
        sum = 0;
    }
```

If `start` and/or `stop` can be negative, the sum can still be computed directly as:

```
    if (start <= stop) {
        // take the sum of integers from 0 to stop - start:
        sum = (long long)(start - stop) * ((long long)stop - start + 1) / 2;
        // add the initial value (stop - start + 1) times
        sum += ((long long)stop - start + 1) * start;
    } else {
        sum = 0;
    }
```

Which simplifies as:

```
    if (start <= stop) {
        sum = ((long long)stop + start)((long long)stop - start + 1) / 2;
    } else {
        sum = 0;
    }
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: the formulae don't work for negative `start` or `stop` values. They work by coincidence for `start == 0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: actually the second formula works for negative values too :)

Answer (score 1):

> Problem in finding sum of consecutive numbers

OP's code repeatedly adds and attempts a sum greater than `INT_MAX` leading to incorrect results.

1. Use a wider type for the computation of the sum such as `long long` or `intmax_t`.
2. Performance: Do not use a loop.  The sum of integers [0...N] is N*(N+1)/2

Instead:

```
//for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
//    z = x + y;
//    x = z;
//    y = y + 1;
//}

// Sum 0 to start
long long sum_start = ((long long) start + 1) * start / 2; // or (start + 1LL)*start/2;
// Sum 0 to end
long long sum_end   = ((long long) end + 1) * end / 2;

//                                                       vvvv specifier change
printf("The sum of the numbers starting from %d to %d is %lld", 
  temp, end, sum_end - (sum_start - start));
```

Comment: You should use *sum of 0 to (start-1)* for `sum_start`.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes - various ways to form a computed `sum`.  ( I did have that fixed earlier in one of my/SO quadruplicated answers).

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you have used a number that is greater than the allowed range for integer data type(it's from `-32768` to `32767` for a 16-bit architecture and from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647` for a 32-bit architecture.) and that's why it leads to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) issue. To fix this problem, you could use other bigger data types such as `long int` or `long long int` but I recommend you use their unsigned data types i.e `unsigned long int` or `unsigned long long int` if you're not going to use negative numbers because the range of unsigned data types begins from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but don't you know the following way to compute the sum?

```
long sum_from_a_to_b(long a, long b)
{
    int n;
    int acc = 0;
    for (n = a; n <= b; n++)
        acc += n;
    return  acc;
}
```

by the way, there's a better formula, which requires no loop:

```
#include <assert.h>
/* assumed that a <= b */
long sum_from_a_to_b(long a, long b)
{
    assert(a <= b);
    return b*(b + 1)/2 - a*(a - 1)/2;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code. I'm a beginner in C language (others call noob). I'm unable to understand your code.

Comment: @RaviKumar, the first snippet of code just goes in a loop for every integer between `a` and `b` (both included)  just adding the values of the loop control variable to the `acc` accumulator.  The second is the result of applied the known formula to get the sum of an arithmetic sequence (look it [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), for a thorough explanation)  You must do some effort to get to it, I only showed you a final working application of that principle.

Comment: @RaviKumar, the problem you are having is that for `1` to `1000000` you finally end adding numbers to the final result which is `500000500000` which is far larger than the full size of an `int` variable.  This is the reason I included `long` typed values in my sample code, the maximum `int` your system allows is `2147483647`, much smaller than that, and the `int` variable is overflowing (wrapping back to `-2147483648` and giving you probably negative results or completely unrelated numbers)

Comment: I understood the "long" and "int" part but what I didn't understood is your program -  
 #include <assert.h>
/* assumed that a <= b */
long sum_from_a_to_b(long a, long b)
{
    assert(a <= b);
    return b*(b + 1)/2 - a*(a - 1)/2;
}

Comment: just execute `man assert` and you'll get access to the documentation of that call.  It just checks the argument to be true, and aborts the program with a message and the location of the call if the assertion is false.  I wrote it as a predicate that must be true always on executing the program.  In case you pass the arguments not in order, the routine aborts.

Comment: by the way, `return b*(b+1)/2 - a*(a-1)/2; is the formula that gives you the sum of the consecutive integers between `a` and `b` (both included).  It allows you to calculate the sum without having to sum all terms (exactly as you don't need to add `a` times `b` to calculate `a * b`)